# Value from the pointer is not displaying correctly

Tags: c, ubuntu-16.04

I try to assign some information to 'char' data (one structure and one integer value), but after i assign it i can't read it back. Any solution? I work on Ubuntu 16.04 installed on virtualbox

```
struct opcode_struct{
    uint8_t a;
    uint8_t b;
    uint8_t c;
    uint8_t d;
};

union opcode{
    uint32_t uint32code;
    struct opcode_struct code;
};

struct request{
    //4
    union opcode opc;
    //4
    uint32_t id;
};


int main()
{
    char *buff = (char*)malloc(32);

    struct request rq = {0x00000001, 0}, *ptr_rq = &rq;
    int val = 512, *ptr_int = &val;

    memcpy(buff, ptr_rq, sizeof(rq));
    memcpy((buff+sizeof(rq)), ptr_int, sizeof(int));

    printf("Request opcode: 0x%08x\n", *buff);
    printf("Request id: %d\n", *(buff+sizeof(uint32_t)));
    printf("Int value: %d\n", *(buff+sizeof(rq)));

    free(buff);
    return 0;
}
```

Displayed text:
Request opcode: 0x00000001
Request id: 0
Int value: 0

but Int value should be equal to '512'

Comment: `struct request rq = {0x00000001, 0}` - which fields do you expect it to initialize?

Comment: `*buff` is a char. Not an integer.

Comment: You might try `*(int *)(buff + sizeof rq)`.

Comment: Wow, thank you @LeeDanielCrocker!!! It worked!

Comment: the posted code will only work if the size of `int` is 32 bits.  I.E. there will be problems if a `int` is 64 bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're dereferencing `buff+sizeof(rq)`, which is a `char *`.  Since 512 is `0x 02 00`, if you dereference it as a `char *` you get `0x00`.  If you look in `buff+sizeof(rq) + 1`, you get the other `0x02`.

On the other hand, if you cast the pointer to `int *`, then you get the full `0x0200`.

```
printf("Int value: %d\n", *(int *)(buff+sizeof(rq)));
```

outputs 512.